# Force two tables stick together in a div when page resize

Tags: html, css, asp.net, visual-studio

I have a div which contains two html tables. When the browser is maximize, the two tables positioned side by side. As I reduce the page size one of the tables positioned under the other. How can I force these two tables stick together in any situation.

```
div{
    width: 100%;
}

.table1 {
    width: 10%;
    float: right;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0;
    overflow:hidden;
}

.table2 {
    width: 90%;
    float: left;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0;
    overflow:hidden;
}

<div>
    <table class="table1">...</table>
    <table class="table2">...</table>
</div>
```

Comment: add `table-layout: fixed;` to both tables

Comment: "When the browser is maximize, the two tables positioned side by side." This is not correct, currently, both tables will stick together as their width is 10% and 90%, which occupies all space in the div.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use flex ?

```
    div{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Try this one**

I use `flex` `for table parent(div)`.

`flex-direction: row-reverse;` , to `table1` to right side.

```css
div {
  width: 100%;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -moz-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row-reverse;
  align-items: center;
}
table {
  height: 75px;
}
.table1 {
  width: 10%;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: red;
}
.table2 {
  width: 90%;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<div>
    <table class="table1"></table>
    <table class="table2"></table>
</div>
```

To know more about [**FLEX**](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

Comment: thanks for reply. Now, I have faced two more problems. The larger table just fill half of the page width although I have set the width to 90%. And is there any way to add a horizontal scroll bar when the page shrinks.Thanks.